# A PMI/PMP Requirements Questions

Tags: requirements, pmp, certification

I have searched and searched online for an answer to my specific question, but haven't found it yet. Can't find the solution on PMI.org either. Maybe you can help.

I have more than 4,500 hours for experience leading and managing project work and more than 36 months of experience... but the hourly experience is spread out over more than 36 months.  This is because some of my full-time work was spent doing non-PM work and I have taken some time off between assignments.  Based on what the Project Management Institute (PMI) is looking for... must the 4,500 hours of experience be attained within the specified 36 month period window? Hence, requiring full-time PM work for 36 months straight?  Effectively, I would satisfy both the hourly and monthly requirements, but not together.

On the actual Project Management Body of Knowledge (PMBOK) 6th Edition-based Project Management Professional Certification (PMP) application, how is the monthly requirement inputted ...or... is it determined by a calculation based on the inputted project dates and hours?  If the later, how is that done?

Comment: This looks like a question for PMI, not strangers on the internet.

Comment: So this means...you don't know??

Comment: It means that any answer you get on this site will be opinion-based, rather than authoritative. Even if someone has personal experience, PMI may have changed their stance since then. It's better to ask PMI directly.

Comment: Funny...I see plenty of similar questions in this forum regarding the PMP ...with reasonable answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in the PMBOK and on the PMI web site. Details may change so I will provide the link.

https://www.pmi.org/certifications/process

There are spreadsheet tools on the web to help collate your experience to help with the application process.

At the time of writing, you need to have the hours in a project within the last 8 years. You do not need to have been a PM, just performed something that falls into one of the knowledge domains.

Comment: When I went for my PMP I was able to use experience over much more than three years. What was most helpful was getting a breakdown from the trainer of the class I took as to usual contemporary breakdowns. So, while I might know that I spent 25% of my time managing a project, this gave me reasonable ways to allocate that time so that I achieved an appropriate balance of work in the various disciplines. (Sorry not to be more specific--this was over a decade ago.)

Answer (score 0):

I am PMP certified and will try to explain. You would need 4500 hours of experience leading or managing projects. This could span across more than 36 months and the projects can overlap. The information about the projects and activities and work hours have to mentioned on the application. The dates rather start and end month timeframes have to be specified. Once you reach the application submission page it gives you a brief idea what needs to be added.